# How to get a youtube video from a keyword with java

Tags: java, youtube-api

How to get a video from a keyword from youtube?

Let say the keyword is "cake"

How to retrieve the url of the first video that comes up when I search "cake"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the YouTube API. Its free and there is a JAVA quickstart guide right here;

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/java

Once your plugged in its very simple you need to use the endpoint;

GET [https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=cake&key={YOUR_API_KEY}](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=cake&key=%7BYOUR_API_KEY%7D)

The response will be something like this...

200

- Show headers -

  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
   "etag": "\"ld9biNPKjAjgjV7EZ4EKeEGrhao/EoHQDcuad8EUkecEhzm0-SiExp4\"",
   "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
   "regionCode": "GB",
   "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1000000,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
   },
   "items": [
    {
     "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
     "etag": "\"ld9biNPKjAjgjV7EZ4EKeEGrhao/paFbDrHLuS3MKVY1Eld-eBZNcss\"",
     "id": {
      "kind": "youtube#channel",
      "channelId": "UCvM1hVcRJmVWDtATYarC0KA"
     },
     "snippet": {
      "publishedAt": "2015-01-31T20:29:19.000Z",
      "channelId": "UCvM1hVcRJmVWDtATYarC0KA",
      "title": "How To Cake It",
      "description": "I'm Yolanda Gampp. This is… HOW TO CAKE IT! New Videos EVERY TUESDAY! SUBSCRIBE: ... Check out my freshest CAKE ...",
      "thumbnails": {
       "default": {
        "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-EusaAtmzWyU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/Z2cn8wKz6xg/s88-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
       },
       "medium": {
        "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-EusaAtmzWyU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/Z2cn8wKz6xg/s240-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
       },
       "high": {
        "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-EusaAtmzWyU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/Z2cn8wKz6xg/s240-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
       }
      },
      "channelTitle": "How To Cake It",
      "liveBroadcastContent": "upcoming"
     }
    },
    {
     "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
     "etag": "\"ld9biNPKjAjgjV7EZ4EKeEGrhao/PZX29oeviKKv4V1id3dJkPaQcyw\"",
     "id": {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "videoId": "fkVFIvLw1qg"
     },
     "snippet": {
      "publishedAt": "2017-09-15T16:08:38.000Z",
      "channelId": "UCHDnCuriJbTe3Cd2FBYA_NA",
      "title": "Top 20 Easy Birthday Cake Decorating Ideas - Cakes Style 2017 - oddly satisfying cake videos",
      "description": "Top 20 Easy Birthday Cake Decorating Ideas - Cakes Style 2017 - oddly satisfying cake videos https://youtu.be/fkVFIvLw1qg Subscribe & More Videos: ...",
      "thumbnails": {
       "default": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fkVFIvLw1qg/default.jpg",
        "width": 120,
        "height": 90
       },
       "medium": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fkVFIvLw1qg/mqdefault.jpg",
        "width": 320,
        "height": 180
       },
       "high": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fkVFIvLw1qg/hqdefault.jpg",
        "width": 480,
        "height": 360
       }
      },
      "channelTitle": "Kinzolai Cakes",
      "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
     }
    },
    {
     "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
     "etag": "\"ld9biNPKjAjgjV7EZ4EKeEGrhao/NqZ6YK7ObLP-wGJ9N6aiHumsQJQ\"",
     "id": {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "videoId": "C3M1fQEVDH0"
     },
     "snippet": {
      "publishedAt": "2017-10-28T11:00:02.000Z",
      "channelId": "UC6CbzmR0ifxxVyFcmXxY5bQ",
      "title": "TOP 10 Awesome Cake Decorating Compilation #16 - Cake Decorating Techniques | Satisfying Cake Video",
      "description": "TOP 10 Awesome Cake Decorating Compilation #16 - Cake Decorating Techniques | Satisfying Cake Video * None of these images, music & video clips were ...",
      "thumbnails": {
       "default": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/C3M1fQEVDH0/default.jpg",
        "width": 120,
        "height": 90
       },
       "medium": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/C3M1fQEVDH0/mqdefault.jpg",
        "width": 320,
        "height": 180
       },
       "high": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/C3M1fQEVDH0/hqdefault.jpg",
        "width": 480,
        "height": 360
       }
      },
      "channelTitle": "UFeedy",
      "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
     }
    },
    {
     "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
     "etag": "\"ld9biNPKjAjgjV7EZ4EKeEGrhao/ZJ1VOmYvgDCkZUvHztaa9uvPFNk\"",
     "id": {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "videoId": "uDzl5PG51uI"
     },
     "snippet": {
      "publishedAt": "2017-10-29T15:00:07.000Z",
      "channelId": "UCpko_-a4wgz2u_DgDgd9fqA",
      "title": "$7 Cake Vs. $208 Cake • Japan",
      "description": "An extra super season 3 finale!” “Stay tuned for season 4!” Food lovers Steven Lim and Andrew, along with their cameraman Adam, embark on the ultimate food ...",
      "thumbnails": {
       "default": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/uDzl5PG51uI/default.jpg",
        "width": 120,
        "height": 90
       },
       "medium": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/uDzl5PG51uI/mqdefault.jpg",
        "width": 320,
        "height": 180
       },
       "high": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/uDzl5PG51uI/hqdefault.jpg",
        "width": 480,
        "height": 360
       }
      },
      "channelTitle": "BuzzFeedVideo",
      "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
     }
    },
    {
     "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
     "etag": "\"ld9biNPKjAjgjV7EZ4EKeEGrhao/G7jIosZqVpAQaeYI21OopfIRf0U\"",
     "id": {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "videoId": "Lk4UJk4VyVE"
     },
     "snippet": {
      "publishedAt": "2017-10-25T11:00:02.000Z",
      "channelId": "UC6CbzmR0ifxxVyFcmXxY5bQ",
      "title": "Amazing Halloween Cake Decorating Ideas Compilation #2 | Most Satisfying Cake Videos",
      "description": "Amazing Halloween Cake Decorating Ideas Compilation #2 | Most Satisfying Cake Videos * None of these images, music & video clips were created/owned by ...",
      "thumbnails": {
       "default": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Lk4UJk4VyVE/default.jpg",
        "width": 120,
        "height": 90
       },
       "medium": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Lk4UJk4VyVE/mqdefault.jpg",
        "width": 320,
        "height": 180
       },
       "high": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Lk4UJk4VyVE/hqdefault.jpg",
        "width": 480,
        "height": 360
       }
      },
      "channelTitle": "UFeedy",
      "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
     }
    }
   ]
  }